# ng-bind-html not updated after ng-click fired

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Recently, I started to study on MEAN stack. I have created a ng-repeat in html, and for each title, I attacked a ng-click function, which is used to show the detail on a overlay popup.

```js
blogApp.controller("blogPanelController",['$scope','$resource',function($scope,$resource){
    var blogs = $resource('/api/blog-list');
    var blogDetail = $resource('/api/blogs/:timestamp', {timestamp: '@ts'});
    
    blogs.query(function(results) {
        $scope.blogs = results;
    })
    
    $scope.generateFloatLayer = function(timestamp){
        
        blogDetail.get({ts: timestamp}, function(results){
            $scope.detail = results;
            console.log($scope.detail.content);
        });
        generateFloatLayer(timestamp);
        
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<!-- for overlay to display detail -->
        <div id="overlay" class="jin-overlay" onclick="removeFloatLayer()"></div>
        <div id="popup" class="jin-popup" ng-controller="blogPanelController" ng-cloak>
                <div ng-bind-html="detail.content | trusthtml">
                    <!-- Hello world blog -->
                    {{detail.content}}
                 </div>
        </div>
        
<!-- list view -->
        <div class="container jin-page-buttom-margin" ng-controller="blogPanelController" ng-cloak>
            <div class="panel panel-info jin-shadow" ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" ng-click="generateFloatLayer(blog.timestamp)">{{blog.title}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" ng-bind-html="blog.content | trusthtml">
                    <!-- html view content -->
                    {{blog.content}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now comes to the problem, after I fired the ng-click, popup could displayed correctly, but no data binding displayed in it.

Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Because your related piece of code is asynchronous this does not work. In that case I wrap my binding into a `$timeout` function:

```
blogDetail.get({ts: timestamp}, function(results){

    $timeout( function() {
        $scope.detail = results;
    } );
    console.log($scope.detail.content);
});
```

Do not forget to inject the `$timeout` into your dependencies!

```
blogApp.controller("blogPanelController",['$scope','$resource','$timeout',function($scope,$resource,$timeout){ ... }
```

Comment: Hi Beat,

I bind timeout function, but it still didn't help. I think the problem should be that the page have already rendered just after I did the click.